# Undefined method find_each for migration - runs the second time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, migration, rails-activerecord

When I run the following migration: "20150121081105_update_interest_group_entries.rb"

```
class UpdateInterestGroupEntries < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    InterestGroupTranslation.find_each do |itt|
      if itt.alias.blank?
        itt.alias = "alias_interest_group_" + Random.rand(100).to_s + itt.locale.to_s
        itt.save!
      end
    end

    PageTranslation.find_each do |page|
      if page.alias.blank?
        page.alias = "alias_page_" + Random.rand(100).to_s + page.locale.to_s
        page.save!
      end
    end

    TestimonialTranslation.find_each do |test|
      if test.alias.blank?
        test.alias = "alias_test_" + Random.rand(100).to_s + test.locale.to_s
        test.save!
      end
    end

    TestimonialInternalTranslation.find_each do |test_internal|
      if test_internal.alias.blank?
        test_internal.alias = "alias_test_internal_" + Random.rand(100).to_s + test_internal.locale.to_s
        test_internal.save!
      end
    end

    InterestGroupInternalTranslation.find_each do |ittinternal|
      if ittinternal.alias.blank?
        ittinternal.alias = "alias_ittinternal_" + Random.rand(100).to_s + ittinternal.locale.to_s
        ittinternal.save!
      end
    end
  end
end
```

It returns this error:

```
==  UpdateInterestGroupEntries: migrating =====================================
-- find_each()
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

undefined method `find_each' for #<ActiveRecord::Migration:0x007f98f8ca0e98>/Users/Vincent/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p550/gems/activerecord-3.2.19/lib/active_record/migration.rb:465:in `block in method_missing'
/Users/Vincent/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p550/gems/activerecord-3.2.19/lib/active_record/migration.rb:438:in `block in say_with_time'
/Users/Vincent/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p550/gems/activerecord-3.2.19/lib/active_record/migration.rb:438:in `say_with_time'
/Users/Vincent/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p550/gems/activerecord-3.2.19/lib/active_record/migration.rb:458:in `method_missing'
/Users/Vincent/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p550/gems/activerecord-3.2.19/lib/active_record/migration.rb:334:in `method_missing'
/Users/Vincent/Documents/remsis/db/migrate/20150121081105_update_interest_group_entries.rb:31:in `change'
/Users/Vincent/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p550/gems/activerecord-3.2.19/lib/active_record/migration.rb:407:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/Users/Vincent/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p550/gems/activerecord-3.2.19/lib/active_record/migration.rb:407:in `block in migrate'
/Users/Vincent/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p550/gems/activerecord-3.2.19/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:129:in `with_connection'
/Users/Vincent/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p550/gems/activerecord-3.2.19/lib/active_record/migration.rb:389:in `migrate'
/Users/Vincent/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p550/gems/activerecord-3.2.19/lib/active_record/migration.rb:528:in `migrate'
/Users/Vincent/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p550/gems/activerecord-3.2.19/lib/active_record/migration.rb:720:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/Users/Vincent/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p550/gems/activerecord-3.2.19/lib/active_record/migration.rb:775:in `call'
/Users/Vincent/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p550/gems/activerecord-3.2.19/lib/active_record/migration.rb:775:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/Users/Vincent/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p550/gems/activerecord-3.2.19/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in `transaction'
/Users/Vincent/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p550/gems/activerecord-3.2.19/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
/Users/Vincent/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p550/gems/activerecord-3.2.19/lib/active_record/migration.rb:775:in `ddl_transaction'
/Users/Vincent/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p550/gems/activerecord-3.2.19/lib/active_record/migration.rb:719:in `block in migrate'
/Users/Vincent/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p550/gems/activerecord-3.2.19/lib/active_record/migration.rb:700:in `each'
/Users/Vincent/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p550/gems/activerecord-3.2.19/lib/active_record/migration.rb:700:in `migrate'
/Users/Vincent/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p550/gems/activerecord-3.2.19/lib/active_record/migration.rb:570:in `up'
/Users/Vincent/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p550/gems/activerecord-3.2.19/lib/active_record/migration.rb:551:in `migrate'
/Users/Vincent/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p550/gems/activerecord-3.2.19/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:193:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/Vincent/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p550/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/Vincent/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p550/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

So it fails on the following lines:

```
InterestGroupInternalTranslation.find_each do |ittinternal|
  if ittinternal.alias.blank?
    ittinternal.alias = "alias_ittinternal_" + Random.rand(100).to_s + ittinternal.locale.to_s
    ittinternal.save!
  end
end
```

When I run the same line in Console it works fine:
[image]

**Strange thing is:**
When I run "rake db:migrate" a second time right after the first,it works as a charm and finishes it:

[image]

I'm running:

ruby 1.9.3p550 (2014-10-27 revision 48165) [x86_64-darwin13.4.0]

Rails 3.2.19

Comment: Didn't you name any of your migration like this?

Comment: You might have another migration named `InterestGroupInternalTranslation` and that one is loaded

Comment: @bcd  I have another migration called "20140904083721_interest_group_internal_translation.rb" why is this a problem?

Comment: Please notice it: http://i.imgur.com/UujsbE3.png

Comment: That migration's class name is the same with the model. Rails loads the migrations classes for the ones that are not migrated. That's why when you run all migration it gives you an error as it cannot find find_each on the migration class. When you run again it will run only the last migration and correctly uses the model class. You should rename the migration class and file name but don't change the timestamp

Comment: @bcd please post this as a reply so I can mark it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have another migration named InterestGroupInternalTranslation and that one is loaded. That migration's class name is the same with the model. Rails loads the migrations classes for the ones that are not migrated. That's why when you run all migration it gives you an error as it cannot find find_each on the migration class. When you run again it will run only the last migration and correctly uses the model class. You should rename the migration class and file name but don't change the timestamp